# How can I remove the 'M' sign in outline of a Jupyter notebook in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I know the 'M' means markdown. But I think it is not necessary and makes the outline hard to read. Does anyone know how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Request tracked here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174104

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of to disable the icon for markdown in the outline is to disable *all* icons in the outline, which you do with this:

```json
"outline.icons": false
```

See issue ticket [#174104](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174104). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".